# Apacite bibliography - last name of authors appear twice

Tags: apacite, bibliographystyle

I am encountering a problem with the \apacite, in which the in-text references appear to be fine but the authors are printed twice in the bibliography. Does someone know how to tackle this problem, thanks in advance!
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please don't share pictures of code, instead include your code directly by surrounding it with tripple back ticks or indenting by four spaces, this way people can copy and paste it to help them solve your problem. Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please confirm that you're loading the `apacite` package.